# How to find first string in a text file with a certain length?

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to write a program that loops through a text file, to find the first word that is longer than 9 characters.

I had thought that I first needed to get a complete word so to do this  I should use a for loop to iterate through each item in the file, adding it to be the currentWord variable.

Secondly, having got this word/String, I would then do the second step - which was to compare its length with the target ('THRESHOLD') length of 9. If it was greater, then I had found the first word of length greater than or equal to 10, and would return this in a sentence. Otherwise, the loop would continue to iterate?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    // Write a program that finds the first word in Alice In Wonderland
// that is longer than a given number of characters.

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class LearningLoops {
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("aliceInWonderland.txt"));
    String longWord = "";
    boolean found = false;
    final int THRESHOLD = 9;
    int i;
    String currentWord; 

    for (i = 0; in.charAt(i) != " "; i++)  {
        currentWord = currentWord + i;
        i++;
    }

    while (in != null)  {
        if (currentWord.length() > THRESHOLD) {
            longWord = currentWord; 
        }
    System.out.println("The first long word is: " + longWord);    
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right approach? I am stuck and so would be grateful for any help.

Comment: in.charAt(i) != " " is wrong..

Comment: Have you tested your approach? If not, why not? If indeed, does it work? If not, what error does it give, or give example input along with expected and actual output, and preferably debug the code to find, or at least narrow down, the issue.

Comment: The right approach should include passing the name of the file you will read to the program as a command line argument.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution would be something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aliceInWonderland.txt"));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() >= 9) {
            return word;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your approach. Do:

1. Use `FileReader` / `Scanner` and/or `BufferdReader` to read the file line by line.
2. `trim()` each line read from the file.
3. Now split the line based on spaces - `\\s+`.
4. Iterate through the array, for each `String` in the split array, check the length. If length > threshold, add the `String` to a `List` / array. if No, do nothing.
5. Do this for all the lines of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops; one `for` loop and one `while` loop.

It's not unusual to do a task in two loops -- perhaps once loop to gather information, then another to process that information. However the task you're trying to do can be done in one loop.

Think about how you would do this manually:

1. Read a word
2. If the word matches your needs, stop and report the word.
3. Otherwise go to step 1

So in your program, first set up the things that will be needed in your loop, then write the loop doing what you need.

That is a loop. In fact it's a `while` loop - you go back to the first step *while* you haven't found a suitable word.

```
 while(word.length < TARGET_LENGTH) {
     word = ... // get next word
 }
```

It looks like you know that a `Scanner` may be useful, but although you create one, you never use it. [Read the documentation for `Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and some methods that are relevant to the problem will jump out at you. Maybe you should try writing a program that prints out the first word, or the first two words, before moving on to tackling the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrongly the Scanner object. It scans the data searching for tokens (see its [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Scanner.html))

Here you have an example using Scanner, but there are other options as other answers are showing (splitting lines into words). I don't like to generate so many String objects, but it's a matter or opinion)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("aliceInWonderland.txt"));
    in.useDelimiter("^\\w"); //any character which is not a letter or number or _
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String s=in.next();
        if (s.length>=9) {
            System.out.println("The first long word is: " +s);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a `BufferedReader`, read the file line by line, split the lines on whitespaces and return the first token that meets the condition.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File("aliceInWonderland.txt");
    int threshold = 9;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.length() > threshold) {
                System.out.println("The first long word is: " + token);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BufferedReader class to improve your performance.Do like this:

```
public static String getLongest() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aliceInWonderland.txt"));
    final int THRESHOLD = 9;
    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
        for(String word: arr) {
            System.out.println(word);
            if(word.length() > THRESHOLD) {
                return word;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps OP needs to get the hang of basic program logic before worrying about performance.